# Convert list of anonymous objects to json array

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

How do I convert my model property:

```
  public List<dynamic> RequestParameters { get; set; }
```

which contains key value pairs to an object that I can pass js functions maintaining the key value pairs as they came in?

Answer (score 0):

okay just figured it out by myself:

in the razor view I can do following:

```
  <text> var parametersObjectAsArray = '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.RequestParameters))'; </text>
```

and then parse it in method with
JSON.parse()